# undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby

```
class ProdutItem
  attr_reader :item, :price_unit, :qtde

  def initialize(item, price_unit, qtde)
    @item = item
    @price_unit = price_unit
    @qtde = qtde
  end

  def calc_qtde
     (price_unit * qtde)
  end

end

 prod = ProdutItem.new("A", 0.50, 3)
 puts prod.calc_qtde

class CalcDiscount
  attr_reader :discount

  def initialize(discount)
    @discount = discount
  end

  def calc_desc
    (price_unit * qtde) - discount
  end
end

desc = CalcDiscount.new(0.20)
puts desc.calc_desc
```

Quando eu executo esse meu codigo acima retorna a seguinte msg de erro:

> teste_04.rb:29:in `calc_desc': undefined local variable or method`
>   price_unit' for #
>   (NameError)
>               from teste_04.rb:34:in `'

```
Eu nao consigo identificar o erro. Alguem poderia me ajudar?
```

Comment: Acredito que você não esteja criando a variavel : "calc_desc"

Comment: `price_unit` não existe dentro da classe `CalcDiscount` apenas na `ProdutItem` e se existir tem de ser acedida com `@`

Comment: Isac, mesmo add o price_unit, continua com erro: teste_04.rb:24:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2) (ArgumentError)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz dessa maneira e funcionou:

```
class ProdutItem
  attr_reader :item, :price_unit, :qtde

  def initialize(item, price_unit, qtde)
    @item = item
    @price_unit = price_unit
    @qtde = qtde
  end

  def calc_qtde
    (price_unit * qtde)
  end

end

class CalcDiscount
  attr_reader :discount

  def initialize(discount)
    @discount = discount
  end

  def calc_desc(product)
    (product.price_unit * product.qtde) - discount
  end
end


prod = ProdutItem.new("A", 0.50, 3)
puts prod.calc_qtde

desc = CalcDiscount.new(0.20)
puts desc.calc_desc(prod)
```

Para calcular o desconto, o método precisa do preço unitario e a quantidade do produto. Devido a isso, adicionei o parametro **product** no método que calcula o desconto para que possamos ter acesso a informação que queremos.